# JavaScript Regular Expression for UK Postcode

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been using this regular expression for validating UK postcodes in my contact forms and it works fine:

```
/^([a-zA-Z]){1}([0-9][0-9]|[0-9]|[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9]|[a-zA-Z][0-9]){1}([ ])([0-9][a-zA-z][a-zA-z]){1}$/
```

however I now need it to be modified to validate with or without a space e.g. GL50 1HX or GL501HX

Is there an easy solution to this?

Comment: What regular expression have you been using?

Comment: So you have a regular expression and you do not show it in your question? Post the code!

Comment: I don't know what could be UK postcodes but for your example this `"GL501HX".test(/^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}\s?[A-Z]{2}$/i)` should work.

Comment: `temp = pcode.replace(/ /g, "")` then test (or use) temp ?

Comment: OK, for your update put `?` after `([ ])` and it will do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify an optional space in a regular expression, put a question mark after it.

Example:

```
^[A-Z]{2}\d{2} ?\d[A-Z]{2}$
```

The question mark is the short form for the `{0,1}` qualifier, i.e. zero or one times:

```
^[A-Z]{2}\d{2} {0,1}\d[A-Z]{2}$
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue - simple as that eh, updated regex for anyone that's interested - /^([a-zA-Z]){1}([0-9][0-9]|[0-9]|[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9]|[a-zA-Z][0-9]){1}([ ]?)([0-9][a-zA-z][a-zA-z]){1}$/

Comment: I would not use this solution: [A-Z]{2} requires two initial characters when many UK postcodes start with a single character, e.g. N1, W1, B1 etc

Comment: @Quango: Sorry for the confusion. The answer doesn't at all claim that the pattern should be suitable for UK postcodes, it just shows how to put an optional space in a pattern.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the regexp that will match UK postcodes:

```
^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]? {0,2}[0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}|GIR ?0AA)$
```

http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=260&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: The question is explicitly asking for something that allows the space to be optional. This requires a space.

Comment: fixed for the space to be optional

Comment: Thank you for answering, this actually caused an error in my js though - invalid quantifier, I've managed to solve the issue with a simple question mark in the end, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Put the space in a conditional regex exp:  `[ ]`

Comment: That is a character class, not a conditional. It means "There must be one of the following characters here: A space (end of list)".